# Checking if a method is attached to an event

Tags: wpf, events

Is there a way in WPF to check if an event has a method attached to it?
I'd like to be able to do something like

```
if (MyEvent != Null)
{
...
}
```

Comment: yes , just like you did here

Comment: as far as i know, this is not possible. an almost same case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716066/checking-if-a-routedevent-has-any-handlers)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating your own `event`, it is possible to check if a method is attached to it or not.

Below I have defined a method `IsMethodAttachedToMyEvent` which will check if the given `Action` is attached to `MyEvent` or not. I have used the `GetInvocationList()` method of `MyEvent` to loop through the attached methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public event Action MyEvent;

        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            MyEvent += new Action(MainWindow_MyEvent);

            MessageBox.Show("Is MainWindow_MyEvent attached\n\n" + IsMethodAttachedToMyEvent(new Action(MainWindow_MyEvent) ));
            MessageBox.Show("Is MainWindow_MyEvent_1 attached\n\n" + IsMethodAttachedToMyEvent(new Action(MainWindow_MyEvent_1)));
        }

        public bool IsMethodAttachedToMyEvent(Action methodToCheck)
        {
            if (MyEvent != null)
            {
                foreach (Action act in MyEvent.GetInvocationList())
                {
                    if (act.Method == methodToCheck.Method)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;

        }

        void MainWindow_MyEvent()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void MainWindow_MyEvent_1()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```